# Postgresql Regex for Word Boundary not Working

Tags: postgresql, unicode, utf-8

Using v9.6.2 (didn't try other versions).

First one works. Second one with a Kanji word fails. What gives?

```
dev=> select 'foo bar' ~ '\ybar\y' v;
 v
---
 t
(1 row)

dev=> select '積極的 積極的' ~ '\y積極的\y' v;
 v
---
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes (Javascript, but I'm pretty sure that the issue is the same.)

Comment: [From the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html): *A word is defined as a sequence of word characters that is neither preceded nor followed by word characters. A word character is an alnum character (**as defined by ctype**) or an underscore.* -- [try with](http://rextester.com/QMJE27595) `COLLATE "zh_CN"`

Answer (score 1):

It'll work without enclosing by `\y`:

```
SELECT '積極的 積極的' ~ '積極的' AS v;
 v 
---
 t
(1 row)
```

`regexp_matches` will work too:

```
SELECT regexp_matches('積極的 積極的', '^.*(積極的).*$') AS v;
    v     
----------
 {積極的}
(1 row)
```

[UPDATE]

Contemporary Chinese characters are rendered using Unicode, which not all programming platforms fully support when it comes to regex [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).  I suppose PostgreSQL isn't using a regex engine that supports Unicode word boundaries.

Some programming languages like Scala (Java as well) do support Unicode with word boundaries:

```
scala> """\b積極的\b""".r findFirstIn "積極的 積極的"
res4: Option[String] = Some(積極的)
```

Note that `\b`, not `\y`, is used for word boundaries in Scala/Java.

Comment: Hmmm, my bad for not noticing word boundary was the focus.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, probably that Postgres doesn't support it. Appreciate your effort.